# How do I bind a GridView to a Custom ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-gridview

I'm trying to bind a customer ContentProvider to my activity that holds a GridView

```
    String[] projection = { SAppsDatabase.ID, SAppsDatabase.COL_APP_TITLE};
    String[] uiBindFrom = { SAppsDatabase.COL_APP_TITLE };
    int[] uiBindTo = { R.id.title };

    Cursor apps =  managedQuery(
           MyProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

    CursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.grid_app_list, apps,
            uiBindFrom, uiBindTo);

    gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is not working.

I manage to bind it to a ListActivity by doing the same as above, and setting:
        setListAdapter(adapter);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work for a `GridView` as the name indicates it is a grid of views

```
GridView is a ViewGroup that displays items in a two-dimensional, scrollable grid. 
The grid items are automatically inserted to the layout using a ListAdapter.
```

but you are providing it a cursor adapter which doesn't make much sense.

Take a look at this [sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html)

If you want to provide a custom adapter then you will have extend adapter and return the view content in the adapter.

Comment: Thanks Ravi. I thought I could get around this. It seems I will need to wrap the ContentProvider around a BaseAdapter.

Comment: When I come back to this part of the development, and implement the wrapper, I'll post it here